# Rows in sql server db being deleted once I click update. the id is only field that has data

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have finally gotten past the errors but now I ham having issue with my DB not being update with my DataGridView data. I don't know why it is not updating.

```
protected void gvKeyPersonnel_RowUpdating(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();
        // SqlDataReader myReader = null;
        // myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        
        
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gvKeyPersonnel.Rows)
        {
            
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE SP2010_EDCStaffing_AppDB.dbo.CMS_Key_Personnel  SET  Name = @Name, VDCIDIQ = @VDCIDIQ, VDCFFS = @VDCFFS, VDCHIM = @VDCHIM, VDCWEBHOSTING = @VDCWEBHOSTING, VDCCWF = @VDCCWF WHERE ID = @id";
                                
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(gvKeyPersonnel.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values[0]));
            
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", row.Cells[1].Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VDCIDIQ", row.Cells[2].Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VDCFFS", row.Cells[3].Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VDCHIM", row.Cells[4].Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VDCWEBHOSTING", row.Cells[5].Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VDCCWF", row.Cells[6].Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing `int @id = Convert.ToInt32(gvKeyPersonnel.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values[0]);` ? this will not add the parameter to your command object instead do `cmd.Paramaters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(gvKeyPersonnel.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values[0]));` do the similar for `@name` parameter as well.

Comment: you need to google msdn command.Parameters.Add method use parameterized query's also wrap all your executing code around a try{}catch you do not need to call `conn.Close();` the using handles that for you when doing auto disposal

Comment: It doesn't like "Parameters". Do I need to set something first?

Comment: Besides the concerns that the previous commenters have raised, are you absolutely certain that `Values[1]` exists?

Comment: Got past the Parameters error. But still getting the OOR range.

Comment: Values[1] shows null. The dgv has a name in that value.

Comment: Hi All, When I debug my code I don't see the @ID or @ Name values. What is wrong with my code? I am a newbie to c#/asp.net. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

you

```
cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE
```

no need `@` just

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE
```

and ensure your connection to database is open by

```
conn.Open();
```